# R: Drawing a textGrob fails with mysterious error

Tags: r, graphics, drawing, plotmath, grob

I have four different kinds of graphic, each converted to a grob with apparent success. I am trying to combine them into a single image with grid.arrange(). One of the four -- I would say the simplest of the four -- produces an error, even without the other three.

```
grid.text(expression(atop("first line", 
                            scriptstyle("second line"))),
            vjust = 0, gp=gpar(fontfamily = "HersheySans"))

Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  Metric information not available for this family/device
```

This is the `traceback()`

```
8: grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, 
       resolveHJust(x$just, x$hjust), resolveVJust(x$just, x$vjust), 
       x$rot, x$check.overlap)
7: drawDetails.text(x, recording = FALSE)
6: drawDetails(x, recording = FALSE)
5: drawGrob(x)
4: recordGraphics(drawGrob(x), list(x = x), getNamespace("grid"))
3: grid.draw.grob(tg)
2: grid.draw(tg)
1: grid.text(expression(atop("first line", scriptstyle("second line"))), 
       vjust = 0, gp = gpar(fontfamily = "HersheySans"))
```

I get the same error if I remove `scriptstyle` and `vjust` from the function, so they aren't the culprits.

I can't even figure out what function the error comes from. grid.Call.graphics isn't exported, but `grid:::grid.Call.graphics` does not have an error message like that in it's code, and neither do `as.graphicsAnnot, resolveHJust`, or `resolveVJust`.

I've hit the wall on this one. Any ideas or suggestions how to resolve this or get around it much appreciated.

All done under Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?Hershey`,

> You cannot use mathematical expressions (plotmath) with Hershey fonts.

which means that Hershey fonts are incompatible with anything listed in `?plotmath`, such as `scriptstyle`, `atop`, and of course `expression`.

Comment: Are you referring to my use of the scriptstyle function? That can not be causing this problem because I got the exact same error when I removed scriptstyle. But I suppose it could cause a different problem when I fix this one. I could not find any documentation for non-Hershey fonts in gpar fontfamily specifications. Are there such?

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I did not realize  That  that was not the base R "expression."